# PHP table appearance

Tags: php, html-table

I wrote some code to display a html table with PHP. 
It reads data from a file and checks whether the value is true or false.

The problem is the ugly appearance of the table at the end of the function:

```
True   False
blue
       Red
       Red
blue
```

I would like to display the table like this:

```
True   False
blue   Red
blue   Red
```

Also it displays the outcome before the function is finished c.q flush();
Here is the code:

```
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>True</th>
        <th>False</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($trimmed_array as $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <?php if (check($value) == 0) { ?>
                <td><?php print $value ?></td>
                <td> </td>
            <?php   
            } else { ?>
                <td> </td>
                <td><?php print $value ?></td>
            <?php
            }
    sleep(1);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    } ?>
</table>
```

I realize this code outputs the table like the first example but I can`t seem to figure out how to change it to fit the second example?

Comment: you should add a `</tr>` and probably `<tbody>` and `<thead>` tags too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code creates one table row per item in the array, so there will always be one blank column per row.

In the 'table' that you would like to display, the items in each row aren't related to each other.

So really you're creating 2 lists here, not a table as such.

I'd do something like this

```
<?php

$all_values = array('true' => array(), 'false' = array());
foreach($trimmed_array as $value){
  if (check($value) == 0){
    $all_values['true'][] = $value;
  }else{
    $all_values['false'][] = $value;
  }
}

foreach($all_values as $name => $values){
?>

<ul class="<?php print $name;?>">
  <?php 
  foreach($values as $value){
  ?>
    <li><?php print $value; ?></li>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</ul>

<?php 
}
?>
```

You can then arrange your lists side by side with CSS

Comment: This looks great but it`s a function that could take several hours (simplified  example) and I also want the output to display before the function ends. Do you have any suggestion where I could implement a flush to print the output before the function is finished?

Comment: I would go with this best. Tables suck.

Comment: I would let Javascript do the HTML rendering. Would be so much easier.

Comment: you could put an ob_flush() / flush() in the `foreach($values as $value){` loop as you did in your code, but obv as one list gets rendered first, if you do have giant lists then you might be waiting a while for the second one. how big are you expecting the lists to be??

Comment: The function check(); -> checks a domain name to be available or not, this takes about 2-4 sec. If the list is filled with (for example) 1000 domains, it takes approximately 40 minutes to execute.

Answer (score 3):

```
$true = array();
$false = array();

foreach ($trimmed_array as $value) {
    if (check($value) == 0) {
        $true[] = $value;
    } else {
        $false[] = $value;
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($true), count($false)); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td>' . (isset($true[$i]) ? $true[$i] : '') . '</td>
        <td>' . (isset($false[$i]) ? $false[$i] : '') . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post something like this. Dang it!

Comment: :) I was faster.. next time :)

Comment: Not a big fan of the `continue` statement though... best using just an `else` for readability, especially for less experienced coders

Comment: @CodeGodie why you removed the arrays assignments?

Comment: @MateiMihai because you do not need them.

Comment: You need them if you don't want to have PHP notices thrown: `Notice: Undefined variable: variableName`

Comment: @MateiMihai oh I didn't know that. How is this notice activated? I have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` but I still do not see this come up. Would it be because that error only applied to older versions of PHP?

Comment: I think that for versions bigger than 5.3 it is not triggered..  but 5.3 is still used at a big scale right now..